# emulate key press on remote machine

Tags: java, keypress

My automated test needs to emulate a keyboard press on a remote machine (something like CTRL+V) 
Testing framework is java based so, is it possible (and how) to do that in java?

Comment: hmm, yes it should bee doable. well, maybe show some efforts on your side? any code effort yet?  but yes, possible

Answer (score 0):

if your remote testing equipment/SW have an input channel you may open a socket to it and send the respective chars, if not - I would look for an local SW with the ability to simulate this keypresses and with such external input channel and use it for that.